# GetSystemMetrics for touch screen is invalid after RDP session

Tags: c#, winapi, rdp

I am trying to work out if the kiosk machine has a touch screen connected. These both work well

```
Console.WriteLine($"Touch3={GetSystemMetrics(95)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Touch2={GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER)}");
```

I can see they both return a result >0 if there is a touch screen present.

All is good until someone RDPs into the kiosk machine. During RDP, there is a prompt on the other machine where the RDP client is running, to say someone else is logged on and whether you wish to continue. As soon as this prompt appears on the RDP client, the values returned by the two lines above are zero. And this does not recover unless you either reboot or unplug the touch screen USB cable and plug it back.

Any way to handle this scenario? The kiosk is running windows 10.

Comment: Does [TouchCapabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.input.touchcapabilities) exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Does that work for windows 10 desktop app?

Comment: I just tested this with a regular console application, and it compiled, linked, ran, and produced the expected result.

Comment: After further investigation, it seems it is a touch screen driver issue. The issue doesn't happen on a surface pro but occurs in a system where the monitor is a touchscreen. So I'm thinking it is a driver issue.

Comment: And unfortunately doesn't seem recoverable unless you unplug the touchscreen USB cable and plug back again.